# How to give a word to button click event function

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to give a string input to the function that is created by the button click event, how do I do this?

```
public async static void De_Click(object sender, EventArgs e,String Name) 
{
    //Code
}
```

Eror

```
De.Click += new EventHandler(De_Click);
```

I know that this error is because the function has a missing input, but how can I give it an input so that there is no problem with its click event?

Comment: The method has to match the event handler, so drop that `string name` parameter.  You can use the Tag property of the button to store things, then in the event method, cast the `sender` to a button and examine that `Tag` value.

Comment: Where does the name come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LarsTech is right, you need to use the Tag property of the button to pass an extra string parameter to your button event handler like below

```
{
//create a new button instance
var button = new Button();
//define your extra sting param
var extraParam = "Am the extra parameter";
//use the tag property to store it
button.Tag = extraParam;
//register an event handler for the button
button.Click += ButtonHandler;
}

//in the method event handler do this
private void ButtonHandler(object sender, EventArgs e){
//get the parameter like below
var param = button.Tag as string; 
}
```

If the string comes from the user input you can declare a string variable inside the class and initialize it to an empty state and then after you get the input from the user, update the variable you just declared with the user input and assign it to the Tag property of the button like in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Is the string variable? Does it come from user input?
The usual way is to read the value of a textbox inside the event handler. If there is no textbox involved, you could always write a custom event handler delegate.
What works in your case really depends on where the string comes from.

Comment: The string is variable and comes from the user input to the class where the button is created and the event is added to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `assignHandler` and a lambda expression, The lambda expression simply invokes the `De_Click` method with the sender parameter and the someData parameter that was passed to the setup method.

```
private void setup(string someData)
{
    Object.assignHandler((sender,args) => {
        De_Click(sender, "name");
    });
}

public void De_Click(Object sender, String Name)
{
}
```

Comment: The assignHandler code gives an error